# How can I listen to a VIM event to run a command AFTER a buffer has been switched to?

Tags: vim, macvim, vim-plugin, nerdtree

When you open macvim with no files it shows a Nerdtree buffer. When you select a file, Nerdtree closes and the new file takes over the buffer. If you open Nerdtree, it shows the root. This only happens the first time.

I want Nerdtree to stay open and reflect the current file (what :NERDTreeFind does).

I have it mostly working:

```
autocmd BufWinEnter * call s:openAndFindNerdtree()


function! s:openAndFindNerdtree()
  " This will only be false, until you open Nerdtree the 2nd time in this scenario
   if exists("t:NERDTreeBufName") == 0
     echo "Find my nerdtree"
     " NERDTreeFind
   endif
endfunction
```

**Here's my problem**:
Right now the `BufWinEnter` event gets called while NERDTree still has focus (before the buffer has been switched).

**My question**:
What event can I use that will fire AFTER the buffer has been switched (focused)?

Comment: Did you try `BufEnter`?

Comment: @FDinoff I did. It appears to behave the same as `BufWinEnter` for my purposes.

Comment: Also, this 'appeared' to work but seems to prevent vim from reading the file into the buffer `au BufReadCmd * call s:getNumberOfOpenBuffers()
`

Comment: Where are you defining this autocommand? Its probably running before nerdtree sets the variable.